Is the swift compiler smart enough to avoid evaluating a let variable declaration that would not be needed if a later condition was not met?
So for example this code:
func trigramSimilarity(to other: Set<String>) -> Double {
    let selfTrigram = trigrams()
    let total = selfTrigram.union(other)
    let common = selfTrigram.intersection(other)
    return total.isEmpty ? 0 : Double(common.count) / Double(total.count)
}

I would hope the compiler transforms to
func trigramSimilarity(to other: Set<String>) -> Double {
    let selfTrigram = trigrams()
    let total = selfTrigram.union(other)
    return total.isEmpty ? 0 : Double(selfTrigram.intersection(other).count) / Double(total.count)
}

By noticing that let common is not needed if total.isEmpty the swift compiler could allow me to write simpler code but avoid unnecessary calculations.
But is it safer to just be explicit?

In general, no. As for this specific case, you can find out by simply inspecting the assembly output. See https://godbolt.org/z/eevYbzaWG for example.

If the optimizer is clever enough to figure out that selfTrigram.intersection(other) has no side-effects (i.e. there's no way to observe that it wasn't calculated), then it would be free to produce code that doesn't call it in the empty case. However, it would be best to just use an if/else here.

For a call like selfTrigram.intersection(other), the compiler has no way of knowing whether the method produces side effects or not — so it has no way of knowing whether the optimization you're proposing is safe to do or not (and so has to be pessimistic about it). There are some operations that the compiler has more knowledge about (specifically, certain things marked as @_transparent or which have @_semantics) but Set.intersection(_:) isn't one of those things.

There has been past discussion about the semantics of a hypothetical @pure attribute (which would indicate to the compiler that a method is free from side effects, and therefore compatible with this sort of optimization), but nothing like this exists at the moment. (Jinx, Alexander)

The compiler could determine this since intersection() is @inlinable, so it has access to the entire implementation. It does not in this case, however.

As you can see in the Godbolt output that Sweeper linked, Set.intersection(_:) is called unconditionally, which is potentially wasteful if total.isEmpty ended up being true.
Your code asks for Set.intersection(_:) to be called unconditionally, so the compiler is obligated to produce code that behaves as if it was really called. The obvious way to do that, is to call it. But it could also get clever and skip calling it, but only if it can be sure that functions has no observable side-effects. That is, if there's no way to observe whether or not it was called. Unless it can prove that, it has to be conservative and leave the call in.
In this case, I think it's more clear to use an explicit if/else anyway:
func trigramSimilarity(to other: Set<String>) -> Double {
    let selfTrigram = trigrams()
    let total = selfTrigram.union(other)

    if total.isEmpty {
        return 0
    } else {
        let common = selfTrigram.intersection(other)
        return Double(common.count) / Double(total.count)
    }
}

The compiled output confirms that common is now only computed if total.isEmpty turns out to be false.
Better yet, I suggest using an early-return:
func trigramSimilarity(to other: Set<String>) -> Double {
    let selfTrigram = trigrams()
    let total = selfTrigram.union(other)

    if total.isEmpty { return 0 }

    let common = selfTrigram.intersection(other)
    return Double(common.count) / Double(total.count)
}

